# Angular refresh after $scope change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

In my app, I am using google maps API v3 so as to show the info window on a map. Info windows are filled with `$scope` values. After the map is loaded, the `$scope` is changed due to an event, however, the content of my info window is still the same.

How can I make it refresh?

I've already try to call `$scope.$apply()` at the end of my event callback function but it didn't work.

**Controller.js**

```
this.fillingMethod = function(){
            info = MyService.getInformation();
            $scope.fillingInfo = info;
}
this.changeAnInfo = function(){
            var info = $scope.fillingInformation;
            var info = MyService.changeInfo(info);
            $scope.fillingInformation = info;
            $scope.$apply();
            }//Google InfoWindow is not refreshed.
```

**View.html**

```
    <!-- ng-controller is defined and refers to Controller -->
    <map id="map-canvas" center="current-location" zoom="15" ng-init="map.fillingMethod()">
        <marker id='test' position="current-location" animation="BOUNCE"></marker>
            <info-window id="marker-info" class="gmarker">
                <div ng-non-bindable="">
                     <div id="siteNotice"></div>
                         <h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">{{fillingInformation}}</h1>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </info-window>
    </map>
<button ng-click="changeAnInfo()" />
```

Comment: @Noémie O'connor update answer, see if it work for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[angular-google-maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/) Check this out. It is google maps for angular. You will have custom directives to use. Just simply put your `$scope` inside, it will update automatically, just like you putting scope in `html tags`.

Check out the API, use `window` directive or `windows`

Edit: there are 2 strange things in your code

- First, why there is `ng-non-bindable` it will prevent angular to compile things inside it. **Try to remove it maybe?**
- The lib you are using doesn't look like much `angular-google-maps` of `angular-ui`. If it is it. Then you will have custom directive/attr. And to update, just simply put info inside the tag.

```html
<map id="map-canvas" center="current-location" zoom="15" ng-init="map.fillingMethod()">
    <marker id='test' position="current-location" animation="BOUNCE"></marker>
        <info-window id="marker-info" class="gmarker">
            <div >
                 <div id="siteNotice"></div>
                     <h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">{{fillingInformation[0]}}</h1>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </info-window>
</map>
```

Comment: Am already using google map for angular. Maybe I don't manage to use it properly since my InfoWindow isn't refresh after $scope update.

Comment: @Noémie O'connor so far I not used it much but it does work for me when using it in a test of fetching some markers through an API. It worked just fine for me. Let's me take a look into your code. Found some strange thing there.